# Multiple Steps/Select In A Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently I am running into a problem where I am trying to run few steps in a cursor but no luck so far.

Goal:
1. Calculate the 'Cross-Sell Rate' for 1 Related Product with 8k Base Products

Logic
1. Retrieve All OrderID that contains the 'Related Product'(TempdbB)(1 time)
2. Retrieve all OrderID that contains the Base Product'(TempdbA)(8k times)
3. Inner Join them to find the common OrderID(TempdbC)(8k times)
4. Count(Common OrderID) / Count(Base Product OrderID) to get 'Cross-Sell Rate'(8k times)(Output into a result table)

My initial thought would be running cursor on Step 2,3,4 for every single base product, then calculate the Cross-Sell rate and insert into a 'Result Table'.

Problem is getting bunch of errors when creating few tempdb with few SELECT statement inside the cursor loop. I am wondering how would I approach this.

Thank you very much and appreciate any help!

Codes Below:

```
-----------------------DECLARE VARIABLES------------------------------------
DECLARE @brand int SET @brand = 1 
DECLARE @store int SET @store = 01920 
DECLARE @sku nvarchar(max)  SET @sku = 'xxx'  -- Related Product- 
DECLARE @vsku nvarchar(max) --USED for Cursor to insert Base Products
DECLARE @startdate datetime SET @startdate = '2018-05-09'  --Set Start Date
DECLARE @enddate datetime  SET @enddate = '2018-05-22' -- Set End Date


------------------------CREATE TEMPDB --------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempA') IS NOT NULL --TempA: Pull ALL ORDERS CONTAINING RELATED Product 
DROP TABLE #TempA
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempB') IS NOT NULL --TempB: PULL ALL ORDERS CONTAINING Base Product
DROP TABLE #TempB
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempC') IS NOT NULL--TempC: PULL ALL ORDERS THAT CONTAIN BOTH Related and Base Product
    DROP TABLE #TempC

CREATE TABLE #Output(
        [BaseProduct] nvarchar(max),
        [RelatedProduct] nvarchar(max),
        [Cross-SellRate] nvarchar(max)
        )

-------TEMPB A: PULL ALL OrderID CONTAINING Related Product-----------------
    SELECT DISTINCT OpOrID, OpPrSKU, OpQty, OpCancelled
    into #TempA
    FROM tblOrder op (NOLOCK) 
    JOIN tblpayment orp (NOLOCK) ON op.oporid = orp.PyOrID
    WHERE orp.PyDateNew BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND opprsku = @sku AND opcancelled = 0


---------------------DECLARE CURSOR-----------------------------------------
Declare x cursor for
Select distinct [Base Product] from tblCrossSellData 

Open x
Fetch Next From X into @vsku

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN


------TEMPB: USE CURSOR TO PULL ALL ORDERIDS CONTAINING THE SPECIFIC ANCHOR Product FOR A SKU LIST 
SELECT DISTINCT OpOrID, OpSoID, OpPrSKU, OpQty, ClID 
    into #TempB
    FROM tblorder op (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN tblProduct m (NOLOCK) ON m.prsku = p.opprsku   
    INNER JOIN tblproclass c (NOLOCK) ON c.prsku = p.opprsku
    INNER JOIN tblpayment orp (NOLOCK) ON p.oporid = orp.PyOrID
    WHERE orp.PyDateNew BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND opsoid = @store
    AND p.opprsku = @vsku AND OpCancelled = 0

------TEMPC: SELECT MUTUAL ORID---------------------------------------------
SELECT DISTINCT a.OpOrID, a.OpSoID
    into #TempC
    FROM #TempA a
    INNER JOIN #TempB b (NOLOCK) ON a.OpOrID = b.OpOrID

-----------------CALCULATION FOR Attachment Rate----------------------------
SELECT @vsku as 'Base SKU', @sku as 'Related SKU', 
CAST(CAST(((CAST((SELECT COUNT(OpOrID) FROM #TempC) as float))
                    /CAST((SELECT COUNT(OpOrID) FROM #TempB) as float)*100) as decimal(18,3)) as varchar(5)) + ' %'
     AS 'Cross-Sell Rate'
     Insert Into #Output

Drop table #TempB
Drop table #TempC

    FETCH NEXT FROM X into @vsku
End

Close X
Deallocate X

-----Retrieve 8k Rows of Base Product, Related Product and Attachment Rate--
Select * from #output

     drop table #TempA
     drop table #output
```

> The Error From SQL IS: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 74 Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'FETCH'.

I tried to switch around the FETCH NEXT Statement, it would just give me msg 156 on different lines.

Comment: post your errors please

Comment: You don't need a cursor here at all. And those NOLOCK hints are extremely scary since this seems to be dealing with money. That hint is far more sinister than most people realize. It means you can and will get missing and/or duplicate rows randomly. There are whole list of other reasons to avoid that hint here. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @scsimon Update has been posted. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: @SeanLange Without a cursor, how would repetitively run these three steps for 8k Products in a query? Thank you for looking into this

Comment: To be honest the body of your cursor is very confusing. You create a bunch of temp tables and throw them away. You also have posted a partial insert statement at the end of the loop. You need to think in sets, not rows. You don't have to do this RBAR (row by agonizing row). What would help the most here is some details of your tables, sample data and desired output. Here is a great place to get started. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Once we have those details we can help you find a set based solution to this.

Comment: You have `SELECT ... ... ... AS 'Cross-Sell Rate' Insert Into #Output` <- try removing the `Insert` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Following Seans proposal, here's a basic code snippet. Since I don't have a SQL Server available, it's just quick'n'dirty:

```
WITH cte as
(Select distinct [Base Product] product from tblCrossSellData),
cte_table_a as
(
    SELECT DISTINCT OpOrID, OpPrSKU, OpQty, OpCancelled
    FROM tblOrder op  
    JOIN tblpayment orp  ON op.oporid = orp.PyOrID
    WHERE orp.PyDateNew BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND opprsku = @sku       AND opcancelled = 0
),
cte_temp_b as
(
SELECT DISTINCT OpOrID, OpSoID, OpPrSKU, OpQty, ClID 
    FROM tblorder op
    INNER JOIN tblProduct m ON m.prsku = p.opprsku   
    INNER JOIN tblproclass c ON c.prsku = p.opprsku
    INNER JOIN tblpayment orp ON p.oporid = orp.PyOrID
    INNER JOIN cte ON p.opprsku = cte.product 
    WHERE orp.PyDateNew BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND opsoid = @store
    AND OpCancelled = 0
),
cte_temp_c as
(
SELECT DISTINCT a.OpOrID, a.OpSoID
    FROM cte_table_a  a
    INNER JOIN cte_table_b b ON a.OpOrID = b.OpOrID
)
Insert Into #Output
SELECT @vsku as 'Base SKU', @sku as 'Related SKU', 
CAST(CAST(((CAST((SELECT COUNT(OpOrID) FROM cte_temp_c ) as float))
                    /CAST((SELECT COUNT(OpOrID) cte_temp_b ) as float)*100) as decimal(18,3)) as varchar(5)) + ' %'
     AS 'Cross-Sell Rate'
```

EDIT: There might be a much more simple code leading to the expected result. But, as Sean stated, we'd need some sample data and expected result. What's confusing is the reference to the two tables tblOrder and tblPayment in both subqueries. Might not be required at all...

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong to me

```
SELECT @vsku as 'Base SKU', @sku as 'Related SKU', 
       CAST(CAST(((CAST((SELECT COUNT(OpOrID) FROM #TempC) as float))
                  /CAST((SELECT COUNT(OpOrID) FROM #TempB) as float)*100) 
            as decimal(18,3)) as varchar(5)) 
       + ' %' AS 'Cross-Sell Rate'
Insert Into #Output
```

`Insert` should be first

Create those #tables and truncate rather than re-create every time.